# How to divide a smaller number by a bigger number in VIM?

Tags: vim

In vim editor, when I try to divide numbers using the command

`<C-r>= 320 / 1024`

I get `0`. How to fix it?

Comment: <C-r>= (320 / 1024) What is the extension?

Comment: try `320.0 / 1024` to make it a Floating Point devision not an integer devision

Comment: Use `1024.0` instead of `1024`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to have one of the numbers as a `float` one:

`320 / 1024.0` will give what you want. More info [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/25.html)

Comment: sorry, I'm a new user, I made a mistake.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is integer division. While doing integer division some sample results are as follows:

```
1/3 = 0
5/3 = 1
```

but converting either the numerator/denominator to a floating point value will return a floating point result.

```
1.0/3 = 0.333333
5/3.0 = 1.666667
```

Therefore what you're looking for is `320/1024.0` or `320.0/1024` or `320.0/1024.0`
The result of which is `0.3125`